# how to store branch name in variable if branch exists?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, branch

```
.some_job:
  stage: stage4
  image: $IMAGE
  script:
    - python3 ./cicd/scripts/build.py master
  when : manual
  only:
    - master
    - main
```

In the script section of this job I want to pass the term 'master' only if master branch exists otherwise I want to pass 'main'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner to do that from a bash shell :

```sh
git rev-parse -q --verify --abbrev-ref master || echo "main"
```

To pass the output as an argument to another command, just use `$( ... )` :

```sh
python3 .../build.py $(git rev-parse -q --verify --abbrev-ref master || echo "main")
```